# \^m exists in LuxiMono Type1 but not in LuxiMono OpenType

Tags: fonts, fontspec

As pointed out by the following MCE, `\^m` exists in the LuxiMono Type1 fonts but not in their OpenType counterpart (the result being weirder with `lualatex` than with `xelatex`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifpdftex
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[scaled=0.85]{luximono}
\else
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmonofont[Scale=0.85]{Luxi Mono}
\fi
%
\pagestyle{empty}
%
\begin{document}
\ttfamily\^m
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to get this character with OpenType LuxiMono?

Comment: While technically any TrueType font is a OpenType font, this one does not contain any of the OpenType specific tables so I would only call it a TrueType font. Even if you get this to work, you will not have any advanced features in this font (no ligatures/no kerning/...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the Luxi Mono fonts you refer to are the ones provided by the X11 system, you can adjust the encoding for them to use a different way for typesetting the accent.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\makeatletter
\DeclareUnicodeEncoding{luxi}{
  \input{tuenc.def}
  \DeclareTextCommand{\^}{\UnicodeEncodingName}[1]{\accent"02C6\relax#1}
  \DeclareUnicodeComposite{\^}              {}{"005E}
  \DeclareUnicodeComposite{\^}             {A}{"00C2}
  \DeclareUnicodeComposite{\^}             {E}{"00CA}
  \DeclareUnicodeComposite{\^}             {I}{"00CE}
  \DeclareUnicodeComposite{\^}             {O}{"00D4}
  \DeclareUnicodeComposite{\^}             {U}{"00DB}
  \DeclareUnicodeComposite{\^}             {a}{"00E2}
  \DeclareUnicodeComposite{\^}             {e}{"00EA}
  \DeclareUnicodeComposite{\^}             \i {"00EE}
  \DeclareUnicodeComposite{\^}             {i}{"00EE}
  \DeclareUnicodeComposite{\^}             {o}{"00F4}
  \DeclareUnicodeComposite{\^}             {u}{"00FB}
  \DeclareUnicodeComposite{\^}             {C}{"0108}
  \DeclareUnicodeComposite{\^}             {c}{"0109}
  \DeclareUnicodeComposite{\^}             {G}{"011C}
  \DeclareUnicodeComposite{\^}             {g}{"011D}
  \DeclareUnicodeComposite{\^}             {H}{"0124}
  \DeclareUnicodeComposite{\^}             {h}{"0125}
  \DeclareUnicodeComposite{\^}             {J}{"0134}
  \DeclareUnicodeComposite{\^}             \j {"0135}
  \DeclareUnicodeComposite{\^}             {j}{"0135}
  \DeclareUnicodeComposite{\^}             {S}{"015C}
  \DeclareUnicodeComposite{\^}             {s}{"015D}
  \DeclareUnicodeComposite{\^}             {W}{"0174}
  \DeclareUnicodeComposite{\^}             {w}{"0175}
  \DeclareUnicodeComposite{\^}             {Y}{"0176}
  \DeclareUnicodeComposite{\^}             {y}{"0177}
}
\makeatother

\setmonofont{luxim}[
  Path=/opt/X11/share/fonts/TTF/,% <--- adjust to your setting
  Extension=.ttf,
  NFSSEncoding=luxi,
  UprightFont=*r,
  BoldFont=*b,
  ItalicFont=*ri,
  BoldItalicFont=*bi,
  Scale=0.8,
]

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\^a \ttfamily\^m\^a\^j

\end{document}
```

[image]

I didn't check that all precomposite glyphs actually exist.

---

Some experience with font encodings is necessary. We declare a new one (there are details in the manual for `fontspec`), called `luxi`. We base it on TU by loading `tuenc.def`, but modify it.

The first change is to redefine `\^` to yield `\accent"02C6` (a spacing circumflex that happily seems to exist in the fonts). However, we don't want to use the `\accent` primitive for already existing precomposed characters such as `â`. So we override the usage of `\^` producing an accented character in case we input, say `\^a`.

When TeX finds `\^x` or `\^{x}` (where `x` is any character), it checks whether a special macro exists, which would have been defined by

```
\DeclareUnicodeComposite{\^}{x}{<slot>}
```

If it exists, then the character in the specified slot is typeset; otherwise TeX goes for `\accent"02C6\relax x`.

Comment: I must admit I don't understand anything! :) But, out of curiosity, why any `m` in the list of `\DeclareUnicodeComposite`?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé There is no precomposed m with hat in the font, because this is not a Unicode character. The precomposite characters are declared separately and might be input as `â` and so on.

Comment: Precomposite characters are declared by `\luxi@accent`? BTW, the latter is defined but not directly used: how a mysterious answer! ;)

Comment: @DenisBitouzé `\luxi@accent` is spurious (a previous attempt), I'll remove it.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I added some comments

Answer (score 1):

If you download the Luxi Mono ttf fonts that are available for free, in my case

```
luximr.ttf
luximri.ttf
luximbi.ttf
luximb.ttf
```

and copy them to the windows font folder (I work on windows)

They are loaded without any error using

```
\setmonofont{Luxi Mono}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
```

Comment: Weird! On my Linux box, with the same fonts installed, my OP's MCE (with your `\setmonofont{Luxi Mono}[Scale=MatchLowercase]` change) still gives an “m” followed by an empty rectangle (m▯) when compiled with `lualatex`, whereas it gives a “Latin Small Letter M With Circumflex” (m̂) when compiled with `pdflatex`.